# how to add a checkbox in a listview?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

i have a question, been stuck for a while, 
i dont know how can i add a checkbox in the list, for example if I have a list of items i want to be able to check them. my xml code is the following:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/middleLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/leftMiddleLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="60px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ListView android:id="@+id/checkboxList" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></ListView>

            <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="test">
            </CheckBox>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/rightMiddleLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout"
            android:layout_width="280px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></ListView>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/text" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>                   
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottomLayout" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5pt"
    >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/insertNewItem"
        android:layout_width="220px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:layout_width="10px" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/addItemButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="Add Item"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

if you have any ideas please let me know, its for my academic studies :((

Thank you!

Comment: cannot solve, seems like an unsolvable problem.  omg. i am stupid apparently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class myAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public myAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);  
}

@Override   
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    cb=(CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cb);
    cb.setText(dbgetStringValue);
    cbText=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cbText);
            cbText.setText(dbgetStringValue);
    cb.setChecked(false);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean isChecked) {            
            if(cb.isChecked()) {                    
                // action
            }
            else if(isChecked==false) {
                // action
            }
        }           
    });
}
}
```

is that what you want?

Answer (score 5):

```
final ListView lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items));
lView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Here item is an array.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you watch this video from the android dev site on how to [Make your Android UI Fast and Efficient](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/videos/index.html#v=N6YdwzAvwOA).  It will give you code to solve your problem and show you the proper way to implement your adapter to make sure it's as fast as can be.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a ListAdapter (e.g. a customized BaseAdapter) on your listView with setAdapter() you can use LayoutInflater inside your adapter's getView() to supply any layout you like for your list entries. This can include a CheckBox.

Comment: OMG, I cannot solve this problem... it's been ages i am stuck on it :(((

Answer (score 0):

Or you can extends any ListAdapter to a subclass and override bindView. Inside of if you would set .setText for the ChecBoxes!

Comment: oh, thanks!
do you know where to find an example of that?
the thing is i am reading the items from the database, using JSON, so i have items. i set a ListAdapter for that, i can see the items. the problem is i cannot find a way to put a checkbox next to each item :(