# how to put checkbox within each row of a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview in which I am getting values from base adapter.what I want that on a click of button, check boxes whose property is invisible gets visible and get appear in front of each row of the list view.I am able to work this thing out but getting check boxes in front of few rows only. I am tired of searching for this thing.I feel problem is somewhere in getting the list view which only fetches view for the rows which are visible on the screen at the time.as I am quite new in this field, I am unable to get my exact problem.any help would be highly appreciable.

///check boxes are appearing in the four rows then again after the gap of two rows and so on..///

```
       button.setOnClickListener(this);
            public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        //relative layout in which button is declared        
                RelativeLayout relative=(RelativeLayout)v.getParent();

        //listview is first child of relative..            
         ListView lv=(ListView)relative.getChildAt(1);

                        for(int i=0;i<lv.getChildCount();i++){

     ////////relative layout in whichcheckbox is declared                        
    RelativeLayout newrelative=(RelativeLayout)lv.getChildAt(i);

    //checkbox is forth child of newrelative..

    CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)newrelative.getChildAt(4);
     cb.setVisibility(0);
                        } 

                }//method
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add a checkbox in a listview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538539/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-a-listview)

Comment: hi have find this any solution..if yes then replay me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` widget recycles its views and that's why you see changes when you scroll up and down.
to solve it you should Override your list adapter and in it decide whether or not to display the `Checkbox`.
the best way to do that is probably saving this data in a database.
then inside the getView method you should add -

```
if (*i should see a checkbox next to this item*) {
    checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    checkbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

the "else" is important because otherwise it will reuse a visible `enter code here`Checkbox with an item that you dont want to have an `Checkbox`.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can get a detailed step by step tutorial for checkbox listview at..[checkbox listview tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Comment: well I have read this article and have done in the way described in the tutorial but I want all this in a click of button.