# Checked States of a Switch in ListView

Tags: android, listview, view, onitemclick, ischecked

I have a custom listview which contains 2 textviews and 1 switch items.When I click switch, nothing happens.Listview onItemClick doesn't catch it, too.I searched the web and ı tried steps below,but nothing happened ,again.

1.I added `android:focusable="false"` definition to each listview custom layout items.

2.This code always returns false for isChecked().

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Switch calendarSwitch = (Switch)adapterView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_switch);
               Log.e("CalendarActivity", " --> " + calendarSwitch.isChecked());
            }
        });
```

3. I couldn't manage to catch any "EventCatched" message on logs with this code.

`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
          Switch calendarSwitch = (Switch) adapterView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_switch);
                    calendarSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                            Log.e("Switch","EventCatched");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });`
```

Thanks in advance, any tips will be very helpful.

Comment: I think adapterView is right choice.Check this link:[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html ]  Anyway, I tried your code, problem is still going on.

Comment: read this `View: The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)`

Comment: Thanks for your reponse so AdapterView refers to listview, and view refers to custom layout for listview.But problem still occurs. @Nilesh Rathod

Comment: This link would be helpful if it had contained  example of checked textviews in listview.@pskink

Comment: @ACrescendo check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538539/how-to-add-a-checkbox-in-a-listview

Comment: @ACrescendo also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940938/use-custome-listview-with-textview-and-checkbox-with-single-selection-of-checkbo

Comment: I don't get it why people still use `ListView` over `RecyclerView`

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo because there are no concrete, ready-to-use implementations of `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Comment: @pskink There are lots of generic implementation of `RecyclerView.Adapter`, you can search it

Comment: @M.RezaNasirloo are they in `recyclerview-v7` support library? i dont think so... thats why people still use `ListView` as they are lazy and dont want to write adapters from the scratch... for example, what generic implementation can do the same thing in `RecyclerView`: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/ ?

Comment: @pskink No they are not. And lots of useful projects like Retrofit and Glide are not in support library too. In case of laziness you are right

Comment: @NileshRathod ı checked your links, I have  3 keywords in my mind to investigate .My code concepts are same with these links except these keywords. (BaseAdapter,SimpleCursorAdapter,ViewHolder)

Comment: @NileshRathod,when I click a switch inside a listview , why  isn't listview OnItemClick callback triggered?